# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument lis

Tags: jquery

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument lis

```
<input id="BUXAR" name="BUXAR" onclick="SearchDistict(BUXAR);" type="checkbox" value="33">

<input id="CHAMPARAN EAST" name="CHAMPARAN EAST" onclick="SearchDistict(CHAMPARAN EAST);" type="checkbox" value="34">
```

> ### MY FUNCTION
>
> ```
> function SearchDistict(obj) 
> {
>   debugger;
>   if (obj.checked) 
>    {
>      districtCollection.push(obj.value);
>    }
>   else
>   {
>      districtCollection.pop(obj.value);
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are passing a string literal as the function parameter, you need to enclose it in quotes

```
<input id="CHAMPARAN_EAST" name="CHAMPARAN EAST" onclick="SearchDistict('CHAMPARAN EAST');" type="checkbox" value="34">
```

---

Server side

```
<input id="<%=d.DistrictName %>" name="<%=d.DistrictName %>" onclick="SearchDistict('<%= d.DistrictName%>');" type="checkbox" value="<%=d.DistrictId %>"><%=d.DistrictName %>
```

Comment: <input id="<%=d.DistrictName %>" name="<%=d.DistrictName %>" onclick="SearchDistict(<%= d.DistrictName%>);" type="checkbox" value="<%=d.DistrictId %>"><%=d.DistrictName %> .can add use Quotes

Comment: @AmitRai `<input id="<%=d.DistrictName %>" name="<%=d.DistrictName %>" onclick="SearchDistict('<%= d.DistrictName%>');" type="checkbox" value="<%=d.DistrictId %>"><%=d.DistrictName %>`

Comment: when we use <input id="<%=d.DistrictName %>" name="<%=d.DistrictName %>" onclick="SearchDistict('<%= d.DistrictName%>');" type="checkbox" value="<%=d.DistrictId %>"><%=d.DistrictName %>                                                                                                                then onclick="SearchDistict('<%= d.DistrictName%>') ;" its show untermineted string constant

Comment: @AmitRai can you check the generated html

Comment: generated HTML is <input id="CHAMPARAN EAST" name="CHAMPARAN EAST" onclick="SearchDistict('CHAMPARAN EAST');" type="checkbox" value="34">  and it works fine but onclick="SearchDistict('<%= d.DistrictName%>') ;"  its show untermineted string constant in html design time.